# Onclick event fires, but append-code is not executed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

In the below Code, the onclick event fires, but the circle is not appended. I have no idea why.

Maybe because of the following mutable?

Code Snippet:

```
.on("click", function (event, d) {
      let center = pathMap.centroid(d.geometry);
      console.log(center);
      
      mouse
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", center[0])
        .attr("cy", center[1])
        .attr("r", 20)
        .attr("fill", "red");

      
      mutable selected = d.properties;
```

Source: https://observablehq.com/@statistikzh/leerwohnungszahlung

Comment: it has defenitly something to do with the mutable that is following

Comment: that is following:

mutable gem_sel.push(d.properties.GDE_ID);
mutable gem_sel = mutable gem_sel;

i have to do the second line, because otherwise the push wouldn't update the mutable gem_sel array correctly.

Comment: Please check if the event is being bubbled up to the parent or not.
Try adding ````event.stopProgagation()```` at the start of the click callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notebook, every time one of the areas in the map is clicked, the map cell is re-evaluated and the entire map gets redrawn. The circles are being added, but then the map immediately gets redrawn from scratch.

If you comment out the lines

```
console.log(colorScaleOrd(d.properties.GDE_ID));
d3.select(this).style("stroke", colorScaleOrd(d.properties.GDE_ID));
```

then you'll see that the circles get added.

The click handler changes `gem_sel`. `colorScaleOrd` depends on `gem_sel` and the map depends on `colorScaleOrd`. The click handler updates `gem_sel`, which causes the cell for `colorScaleOrd` to be re-evaluated, which causes the cell that draws the map to be re-evaluated. There's kind of a circular dependency.

To reference the [Introduction to Mutable State](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-mutable-state) notebook, you should try to avoid using mutable state on Observable to prevent these kind of issues.

> *Note: The `mutable` keyword is easy to misuse in a way that makes it more difficult to successfully write Observable notebooks! Think of it as an **escape hatch** for those rare cases where you find the need to bypass Observable’s reactive dataflow model.*

Edit: I've created a [fork of your notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/c66e85cf3f0eaee2) to demonstrate one way of building this visualization without using `mutable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dan! i tried to do it with Object.assign(... at the end and then found the mutables and thought they were a good idea. Thanks for pointing me to the Introduction.

Comment: now i get it! really great Dan, this helped a lot